# Подскажите какие ошибки я сделал?

Tags: css, html5, вёрстка, инспекция-кода, flexbox

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:200|Merriweather+Sans:800i|PT+Sans:400,700|Slabo+27px|Tajawal');
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/*/ Header /*/

header {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.logo {
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  font-size: 40pt;
  color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 51px;
}

.topnav ul {
  font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16pt;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -o-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 55px;
}

.topnav li {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

.topnav li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.topnav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}


/*/ End Header /*/


/*/ BIlboard page /*/

div.bilboard {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -o-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -o-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-image: url(../img/bg.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 652px;
}

.title {
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.title h1 {
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  font-size: 50pt;
  word-spacing: 20px;
  color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
}

.title p {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16pt;
  word-spacing: 5px;
  color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
  margin-top: 33px;
}

.btn {
  -ms-align-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  font-size: 18pt;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 43px;
}

.btn a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  width: 291px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 18px 77px;
}

.btn a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(77, 77, 77, .5);
}


/*/  End BIlboard page /*/


/*/ Service page /*/

.service {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -moz-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  -o-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 425px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(77, 77, 77);
}

.s1 {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -o-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 340px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 99px;
}

.service .s1 h3 {
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22pt;
  word-spacing: 8px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.service .s1 p {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14pt;
  word-spacing: 5px;
  margin-top: 44px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
}


/*/  End Service page /*/


/*/ Video page /*/

.video {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -o-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 82px;
}

.titleplay {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -o-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 737px;
  text-align: center;
}

.titleplay h2 {
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  font-size: 30pt;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  word-spacing: 8px;
}

.titleplay p {
  -ms-align-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14pt;
  word-spacing: 5px;
  max-width: 495px;
  margin-top: 27px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
}


/*/ End Video page /*/


/*/ Work page /*/

.work {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -o-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
}

.work h2 {
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30pt;
  word-spacing: 8px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.brand {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -moz-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  -o-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-align-items: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 320px;
  margin: 80px 0 95px;
}

.brandname {
  display: block;
  width: 260px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247);
  margin-right: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.brandname:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.brandtitle {
  margin-top: 140px;
}

.brandname h3 {
  font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25pt;
  color: rgb(210, 209, 209);
  padding: 0;
}

.brandname p.tl {
  font-size: 10pt;
  color: rgb(210, 209, 209);
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.prj {
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  font-size: 13pt;
  margin-top: 58px;
}

.prj a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgb(87, 87, 87);
  max-height: 60px;
  max-width: 260px;
  padding: 25px 20px;
}

.brandname:hover .prj {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
}


/*/ End Work page /*/


/*/ Journal page /*/

div.journal {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -o-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -o-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
  height: 362px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-top: 97px;
  padding-bottom: 90px;
}

.titlejournal {
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.titlejournal h1 {
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  font-size: 30pt;
  word-spacing: 26px;
  color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.titlejournal p {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14pt;
  word-spacing: 5px;
  color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
  margin-top: 33px;
}

.sbsk {
  -ms-align-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  font-size: 18pt;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 55px;
}

.sbsk a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  width: 307px;
  height: 48px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  transition: .3s;
}

.sbsk a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  transition: .3s;
}


/*/ End Journal page /*/


/*/ Social page /*/

.socialdiv {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -moz-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  -o-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 450px;
  height: 270px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.social {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -o-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.social a {
  -ms-align-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: .3s;
}

.google-pluse a:hover {
  background: #DD4B39;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid white;
  transition: .5s;
}

.twitter a:hover {
  background: #00acee;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid white;
  transition: .5s;
}

.facebook a:hover {
  background: #3b5998;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid white;
  transition: .5s;
}

.vk a:hover {
  background: #5d84ae;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid white;
  transition: .5s;
}

.google-pluse a:active {
  opacity: 0.1;
}

.twitter a:active {
  opacity: 0.1;
}

.facebook a:active {
  opacity: 0.1;
}

.vk a:active {
  opacity: 0.1;
}


/*/ End Social page /*/


/*/ Contact footer /*/

footer {
  background-color: rgb(59, 59, 59);
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 140px 0 135px 0;
}

.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.list {
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 274px;
}

.list ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.list h3 {
  font-style: 18pt;
}

.list li {
  font-style: 14pt;
  color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
  margin-top: 13px;
}

.list li:first-child {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.list a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
  transition: .3s
}

.list a:hover:not([class="blank"]) {
  color: rgba(235, 235, 235, .5);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(235, 235, 235);
  transition: .3s;
}

.list a.blank {
  text-decoration: underline;
  transition: .3s;
}

.list a.blank:hover {
  color: rgba(235, 235, 235, .5);
  transition: .3s;
}

.location a.blank {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 17px;
}

.minimaco p {
  color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
  margin-top: 40px;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.minimaco p:last-child {
  margin-top: 25px;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>projeckt</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="logo">
      Minima
    </div>
    <div class="topnav">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#serv">Service</a></li>
          <li><a href="#ost">Our Story</a></li>
          <li><a href="#wk">Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="#jl">Journal</a></li>
          <li><a href="#ct">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="bilboard">
    <div class="title">
      <h1>
        Minima Clean &#38; Minimal Template
      </h1>
      <p>
        excepteur sint occaecat cuplidatat non proident
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
      <a href="#">start here&#8594;</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="serv" class="service">
    <div class="s1">
      <img src="img/Shape1.png" alt="1">
      <h3>Duis aute irure</h3>
      <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupi datat non it proident, sunt in culpa qui officia dese runtorn mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="s1">
      <img src="img/Shape2.png" alt="2">
      <h3>Duis aute irure</h3>
      <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupi datat non it proident, sunt in culpa qui officia dese runtorn mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="s1">
      <img src="img/Shape3.png" alt="3">
      <h3>Duis aute irure</h3>
      <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupi datat non it proident, sunt in culpa qui officia dese runtorn mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ost" class="video">
    <div class="titleplay">
      <h2>sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit</h2>
      <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="play"><iframe width="686" height="383" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0MO9M_vjlkY" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
  </div>
  <div id="wk" class="work">
    <div class="titlework">
      <h2>Recent Work</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="brand">
      <div class="brandname">
        <div class="brandtitle">
          <h3>BRAND</h3>
          <p class="tl">tagline here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="prj"><a href="#">Brand Project &#8594;</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="brandname">
        <div class="brandtitle">
          <h3>BRAND</h3>
          <p class="tl">tagline here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="prj"><a href="#">Brand Project &#8594;</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="brandname">
        <div class="brandtitle">
          <h3>BRAND</h3>
          <p class="tl">tagline here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="prj"><a href="#">Brand Project &#8594;</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="brandname">
        <div class="brandtitle">
          <h3>BRAND</h3>
          <p class="tl">tagline here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="prj"><a href="#">Brand Project &#8594;</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="jl" class="journal">
    <div class="titlejournal">
      <h1>
        join our subscribers.
      </h1>
      <p>
        10 000 sint occaecat cupidatat non proident sunt in culpa qui officia.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="sbsk">
      <a href="#">Click here to subscribe</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="socialdiv">
    <div class="social google-pluse">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-2x"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="social twitter">
      <a id="link" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="social facebook">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="social vk">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-vk fa-2x"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="list location">
        <h3>Location</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>1401 South Grand Avenue</li>
          <li>Los Angeles, CA 90015</li>
          <li><a href="(213)748-2411">(213) 748-2411</a></li>
          <a class="blank" href="#">see it in the map&#8594;</a>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="list company">
        <h3>Company</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#ost">Our  story</a></li>
          <li><a href="#serv">Mission</a></li>
          <li><a href="#jl">Journal</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="list support">
        <h3>Support</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Policies</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="list minimaco">
        <h3>Minima.</h3>
        <p>ed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliwua.</p>
        <p>Template made by <a class="blank" href="#">pixelhint.com</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Попробовал сделать свой первый простой макет. Хотел бы сразу узнать что сделал не так.И провести работу над ошибками.
https://github.com/maxburtsev/MyFirstMaket.git

Comment: а что конкретно интересует ?

Comment: Если у вас есть какие то конкретные вопросы - спрашивайте. Тут не занимаются код ревью. Можете проверить себя через validator.w3.org или google lighthouse

Comment: @DiDex занимаются, даже метка есть [tag:код-ревью].

Comment: Максим, пожалуйста добавьте код прямо в вопрос (кнопка [edit], скопировать, выделить и Ctrl+K для оформления кода, сохранить). Правила сайта такие, ссылки недостаточно.

Comment: А вообще, добро пожаловать на сайт )

Comment: @NickVolynkin добавил код.